# PipeReader CancelPendingRead not cancelling current read operation

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.pipelines

I expected to be able to start another read operation if I cancel the current read with `CancelPendingRead`. But this code throws a `InvalidOperationException`. Does `CancelPendingRead` not work as i think or what could be the problem?
I'm testing with .Net Core 3.1.

```
try
{
    var p = new Pipe();
    await p.Writer.WriteAsync( new Byte[] { 1, 2, 3 } );

    var rr = await p.Reader.ReadAsync();
    p.Reader.CancelPendingRead();

    rr = await p.Reader.ReadAsync(); // Reading is already in progress.
}
catch ( InvalidOperationException ex )
{
    Console.WriteLine( ex );
}
```

Comment: There is no pending read, you awaited it.

Comment: @HansPassant I knwo...now. I misunderstood `CancelPendingRead`, I thought I could use `CancelPendingRead` to start another read without calling `AdvanceTo` (e.g. shortcut for `ReadAsync` + `AdvanceTo( buffer.Start )`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the problem:
`CancelPendingRead` does cancel a waiting read. It does **NOT** not "cancel" a already executed read. The solution is to advance the reader to the start of the just read buffer.

```
var p = new Pipe();
var readTask = p.Reader.ReadAsync();

p.Reader.CancelPendingRead();

var rr = await readTask;
// rr.IsCanceled; => is true
p.Reader.AdvanceTo( rr.Buffer.Start );
rr = await p.Reader.ReadAsync();
```